# Clojure read-line function problem

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to get console input in my Clojure program, but when it gives me this error when it gets to that part of the program.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
clojure.lang.LineNumberingPushbackReader cannot be cast to java.io.BufferedReader
```

the 'read' function works, but it's not what I need. Here is the code I'm using.

```
(defn prompt-read [prompt]
  (print (format "%s: " prompt))
  (flush )
  (read-line))
```

EDIT:

It is obviously just the version I'm using. It's the version included in the current sample code of Programming Clojure, I'll test out the current release version and see if that is the problem.

Comment: Just fyi, at http://github.com/stuarthalloway/programming-clojure/tree/master Halloway includes a copy of clojure and clojure-contrib that are the versions he uses for the book in it's current form.

Comment: Yeah, those are the ones that failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, it seems to work for me. What version of Clojure are you using and how are you calling prompt-read? Here's what I'm getting back (here `goo` is my response):

```
user=> (defn prompt-read [prompt]
(print (format "%s: " prompt))
(flush )
(read-line))
#'user/prompt-read
user=> (prompt-read "foo")
foo: goo
"goo"
```

Comment: Yes sir that was the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Of course. Clojure's been changing a lot lately so I've run into a lot of similar problems between the first beta of the book and the current beta (but apparently this will calm down a bit soon).

Answer (score 1):

The read-line problem was a known bug. It was fixed. Update your Clojure version.