# What is Clojure's flush and why is it necessary?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have a very limited understanding of functional programming at the moment, and I'm trying to wrap my head around Clojure.

I noticed an issue when I tried to `print` before using `read-line`
 where I got the opposite. Then [I came across this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509250/clojure-read-line-function-problem) and noticed `flush`. It worked.

But why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `print` writes to the `*out*` which by default is `java.io.PrintWriter`. `PrintWriter` does internal buffering and if you don't fill its current buffer it won't pass the data through to the output console. By using `flush` you call the `PrintWriter`'s [`flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush--) method which forces the buffers to be flush to the downstream output (probably your console).